# How does a CORS unblocker work from client side?

Tags: javascript, html, cors

As far as I know, websites that don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be fetched using `XMLHTTPRequest` from client side so this problem can be solved only from server side by adding `*` to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  in the header section.

```js
let url = 'https://tv.jordkris.com';
fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
.then((text) => {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var html = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  target.innerHTML = text;
})
.catch(err => console.error(err.message));
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

However, recently I came across [a website](https://corsproxy.io/) that can perform CORS unblocking of a URL.

```js
let url = 'https://corsproxy.io/?' + encodeURIComponent('https://tv.jordkris.com');
fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
.then((text) => {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var html = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  target.innerHTML = text;
})
.catch(err => console.error(err.message));
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

How does the website work so that it can unblock CORS from the client side?

Comment: It's not unblocking from the client-side. It's unblocking it on the `corsproxy.io` server.

Comment: And this means, incidentally, that the folks running corsproxy.io can see every bit of data you send this way. API keys, PII, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then how can that website unblock CORS?

Comment: They are sending permissive CORS headers, which allows you to send requests to them. They are then sending the request on server-to-server, where CORS doesn't apply.

Comment: Clearly you know how CORS solved server-side - by proxying the actual service either through the same domain (no need for CORS headers) or some other domain with correct headers. Could you please clarify why you expect that some other site can't do the same on demand?

Comment: @ceejayoz is there an object or environment where CORS is not applied?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I ask this just for clear explanation purposes, no more.

Comment: CORS is applied to client-side requests. It does not apply to server-side requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is designed to protect data that the browser can access from third parties.

e.g.

- Alice runs a company Intranet
- Bob has a browser on the company LAN that can access said Intranet
- Mallory runs an evil website that wants to steal data from the Intranet

The Same Origin Policy prevents JavaScript on Mallory's website from making an HTTP request to Alice's Intranet from Bob's browser and then passing the data back to Mallory.

Meanwhile:

- Chuck runs a nice website that Alice wants to share data from the Intranet with (e.g. it is used for Single Sign On)

CORS allows Alice to let Chucks website read the data using Bob's browser.

Then along comes Dom who runs another website and wants to access Alice's Intranet *directly*.

Scenario 1:

Dom's server side code tries to make an HTTP request to the Intranet, but Dom's website isn't on the LAN so there is no route to it, and the request can't make it. Dom can't access it.

Scenario 2:

Dom's website **is** on the LAN, can access the Intranet and then can do anything Dom wants with it: Including serving up a copy of the data to a web browser, optionally adding CORS headers to grant permission for that browser to access it across origins. Since the browser is accessing it from Dom's website, the configuration of Alice's website is irrelevant.